# A new column in PowerBI that states whether the customer has been handled by this employee before

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to make a new column that explains whether or not the particular customer no. has been handled by the employee before.

So I have the following table: Customer_ID, BookingDate, Profile_ID, Returning Customer (Yes/NO), order status. I want to add RC (Returning customer) for employee.

[image: Image of table, green is what i try to achieve]

So my conditions for the column is that: They have been customers before, so Returning customer: Yes. They have been served by this employee before (Profile_ID) and the order status must be active, before it counts as a returning customer.

I have tried the following DAX code, but something about is wrong, because I can see it produces wrong results in the column - I believe there must be an easier way to do this, since I already have made the "Returning customer" column.

```
ReturningCustomerforT = 
VAR mycount = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(orders),
FILTER(
    ALLEXCEPT(orders, orders[Column1.Customer_ID]),
orders[Column1.Profile_ID] < EARLIER(orders[Column1.Profile_ID]
) ) )
RETURN IF (mycount > 0 && orders[Column1.OrderStatus] = "Active", "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the "Returning Customer",you will need a more simple filter than "RC for employee". I will only show you the "RC for employee" as the other you can figure out from it and I also believe there you have a problem.

As you are only at "Active" orders, we need to filter them out you did this in the if clause but this is more effective in the filter.

```
RC for employee =
    VAR custID = orders[Column1.Customer_ID]
    VAR profID = orders[Column1.Profile_ID]
    VAR orderDate = orders[BookingDate]
    VAR orderCount = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(orders), FILTER(orders, custID = orders[Column1.Customer_ID] && profID = orders[Column1.Profile_ID] && orderDate >= orders[BookingDate] && orders[Column1.OrderStatus] = "Active"))
RETURN IF (orderCount > 1, "Yes", "No")
```

So for each row of the table we will match orderid, profileid and check if orders are active, we also compare on date so all earlier bookings are included in the count.